# magento 2 print_r log is giving errors

Tags: magento2, log

```
 /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
    $quote = $this->session->getQuote();
    /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item[] $quoteItems */
    $quoteItems = $quote->getAllItems();
    foreach ($quoteItems as $quoteItem) {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/express.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info(100,print_r($quoteItems,true));
        if (in_array($quoteItem->getSku(), $this->disabledForSku)) {
            return false; // disable the method if we found product with specified sku
        }
    }
```

This is the code I am using for print_r but this is displaying blank page.

Comment: yes because it will write your log into var/log/express.log file . Go to that directory and check that file .

Comment: that file is showing empty 0B

Comment: No for m2 its not , check this link for more details - http://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-logging/

Comment: thanks. but actually what i need is, i want the values of foreach in a new log

Answer (score 7):

`print_r` with Magento models often results in exhausting the memory limit because it prints all the dependencies which can be hundreds of complex objects, sometimes even in circular dependencies.

Instead, use `print_r($object->debug())`, the `debug` method only returns the `_data` array instead of all properties and also detects recursion.

Since you are dealing with an array, you have to call `debug` on all items. You can let Magento do it automatically for you by putting the array into a simple `DataObject`:

```
print_r((new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(['items' => $quoteItems]))->debug());
```

or map the array yourself:

```
print_r(array_map(function($item) { return $item->debug(); }, $quoteItems));
```

Answer (score 1):

This Works for me if you want to print arrays in log

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/express.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info(print_r($quoteItems, true));
```

If you are using windows make sure you change slash for path you define

```
\var\log\express.log
```

Comment: $quote = $this->session->getQuote();
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item[] $quoteItems */
        $quoteItems = $quote->getAllItems();
        foreach ($quoteItems as $quoteItem) {
            if (in_array($quoteItem->getSku(), $this->disabledForSku)) {
                return false; // disable the method if we found product with specified sku
            }
        }

Comment: after foreach i have kept your log but still showing blank page, i also did flus h cache

Comment: after foreach try this `$logger->info(print_r($quoteItem->getData(), true));`

Comment: did the same but no result

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below code.

```
$writer_fail = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/express.log');
$logger_fail = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger_fail->addWriter($writer_fail);
$fail = "you can set your error here";
$logger_fail->info($fail);
```

please make ensure the log file is proper permission is to be set.

Comment: where can i put print_r ?